# 70's or 80's space prison escape movie, reprogramming the prison’s pleasure robots for the escape

Tags: story-identification, movie, space

I saw this movie on TV sometime in the 80's. It's basically *Escape From Alcatraz* set in a space prison, definitely made in the 70's or early 80's. There's a small group of prisoners plotting and preparing to escape. The prison has pleasure robots for the inmates that say things like “I like to please you!” and they reprogram one of them in the breakout attempt. I can find no trace of this film anywhere.

Comment: A prison with "pleasure robots"?

Comment: @Deion - Plot twist : They all look like Madeline Albright.

Comment: My initial thought was [Fortress 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zB4WcWfQ6tM) which takes place in a space prison, but doesn't feature the pleasure bots and is from the late 90s.

Answer (score 5):

The name of the film is Escape from DS-3 (1981)

I've watched this film a few times and only managed to find it's name because I remembered Bubba Smith (High Tower from Police Academy) was in it.

Tag from IMDB :

YEAR: 2045 - PLACE: Detention Satellite 3, Maximum Security Prison - MISSION: To Get Out Alive!!!

He was accused of a crime he didn't commit. Now Andrew Lavette must prove his innocence and regain his freedom.

I hope the link works, if not there are samples on Youtube, with clips with Pleasure robots.

Comment: That's it. THANK YOU! Your kung fu is the best. Now I can move on with my life.

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about *[Slave Girls from Beyond Infinity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slave_Girls_from_Beyond_Infinity)*? [IMDB link](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0093991/)

> Daria and Tisa, two nubile female prisoners, clad only in rough-cut rabbit skin bikinis, break out of their cell in a space gulag, overpower their guards, and escape in a shuttlecraft.
>
> The ship mysteriously malfunctions and the girls crash land on a nearby habitable world where they become the guests of Zed, a man with a scarred face who lives in a large fortress. He is the planet’s sole sentient inhabitant and is guarded by two robots who also act as the fortress' keepers.

Comment: The prison scenes are only at the beginning and, while the movie is known for a lovemaking scene with a robot observing, it's between two of the humans. Nevertheless, I thought it would be helpful to have more than a link-only answer.

Comment: that... sounds awesome.

Answer (score -2):

What about 1981's Outland with Sean Connery?

Comment: Not a prison planet, no sexbots.

Comment: This is a very poor quality answer since it doesn't explain how it fits the question (and actually does not)

Comment: Please explain how this matches